# How to cover sphere by hexagonal modules?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have chosen to make a spherical planet, that is populated by hexagon tiles. As part of a school project, I need them to be fully customizable, and have chosen to do it by realizing them as Instances.

As for the GeoNodes, I am creating an IcoSphere and turning it into a DualMesh, splitting faces, etc... Shortly said, I have exactly what I want, but only in geometry. In my case I need them to be individual Instances. So I generate points on each face, to realize my new "Hexagon Instances" on, and it works, except their individual rotation.

This is what I'm asking for. Is there any way for me to make the tiles/points rotate according to the original mesh, so that they **line up nicely**?

[image: instances]

[image: dualmesh]

[image: nodesetup]

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can get there just by distributing hexagon instance since *Dual Mesh* node generates also pentagon faces (differs not only by edge count, but also by size).

[image]

*Since no one here is partial answer* ... To distribute hexagon and pentagon instances according source face can be solved by **Face Area** node.

Rotation - Luckily pentagon instances (in blend file below) are rotated OK (except top&bottom one switched 180°) ... but with hexagons I'm not sure if there is a way to define how instances should orient. One Axis is easily taken from Normal direction, but how to set two others? With one more Align Euler to Vector I can get top hexagons loop rotated right, but the rest is 90° off ... I could separate them and rotate after that, but there are still some of them incorrect ...

Anyway there are two main issues with dual mesh topology...

- hexagons are not all rotated from top to down same (they are partly pointed up by vertex and partly by edge)
- hexagons are not the same size and shape so instances will never match source

[image]

---

### Workaround

Probably could be enough to **Split Edges** and transform elements instead of using instances as base.

[image]
[image]

Than you can try distribute Trees or Stones on faces by Selection of your choice (here just random) and for the same group of selection used specific material ... but yes, it would not work in all cases.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @quellenform ... any idea at year 23 :)

Comment: So far, I haven't found a satisfactory idea in this case, except for the one you suggest here. I'm afraid it won't work on a sphere with hexagonal instances (unless you accept a few pentagons).

Comment: Hello! Your answer has proven very helpful, but as you said yourself, it still has some issues when it comes to individual instance rotation. I was aware that there were some pentagons present, but i've just hoped that the hexagons would instance over it anyway. I didn't know it would affect the normals that much :/.

I have chosen to do the planet with instances, because i want to be able to instantiate a collection of objects (hex tiles with forests, rocks and some other objects on it). This would be defined using noise, or some other data...

Do you think there's a different way?

Comment: You can find a trillion of topics why it is not possible to cover sphere by hexagons [Goldberg_polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron) ... off topic, just for fun [visual illusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWIIy4eh6bE)

Comment: If you are OK with a few pentagons, check my edit ...