# Hexagon shell tool

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm looking for a tool that can turn a 3D object into a shell with hexagon holes. It should be parametric, so the option to change the size, distance between, rotation of the hexagon shape.

I made this drawing to show what I'm looking for:
[image]

[image]

I did try to make it myself with GeometryNodes, but it's not good.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can cover such capsule by even hexagonal pattern ... even Sphere contains a few pentagons https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282714/2214

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can cover any shape just by hexagonal pattern. You will always deal with other n-gons. [Like here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/282714/2214) for sphere you end up with some pentagons. (Here you can find [deeper explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldberg_polyhedron).)

---

If you are OK with that ... so for the simplification - you can generate something if your mesh will be **triangulated** (even as possible) and you use **Dual Mesh** node ... like here if I start with IcoSphere, split at half, bridge the gap with 3 cuts, later rotate one ring at left and right side from centre about 18°, search for triangulate mesh, and add GeoNodes with Dual Mesh node.

[image]

*Apply* GN modifier, select all vertices, search for *Inset* (I) *Individual* (I), add *Solidify* modifier ...

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you, it does look like what I'm looking for. But I do not understand how you did it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I added only blend file, because this solution is not parametric and doesn't work for a cube ... so I don't think this is what are you looking for. The only one shape that it will work for is a Tube (Cylinder).